# A closed form for $\int_0^1{_2F_1}\left(-\frac{1}{4},\frac{5}{4};\,1;\,\frac{x}{2}\right)^2dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

Is it possible to evaluate in a closed form integrals containing a squared hypergeometric function, like in this example?
$$\begin{align}S&=\int_0^1{_2F_1}\left(-\frac{1}{4},\frac{5}{4};\,1;\,\frac{x}{2}\right)^2dx\\\vphantom{=}\\&=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_0^1\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4n+1}{8^n}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(2n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(n+1)^2}\cdot x^n\right)^2dx\end{align}$$
It is approximately
$$S\approx0.8263551866500213413164525287...$$

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your integral has an elementary closed form, that was correctly stated by Cleo in her answer without proof:
$$S=\int_0^1\left({_2F_1}\!\left(-\tfrac14,\tfrac54;\,1;\,\tfrac{x}2\right)\right)^2dx=\frac{8\sqrt2+4\ln\left(\sqrt2-1\right)}{3\pi}.\tag1$$

---

*Proof:*  Using [DLMF 14.3.6](http://dlmf.nist.gov/14.3#E6) we can express the hypergeometric function in the integrand as the [Legendre function of the $1^{st}$ kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) (also known as the [Ferrers function of the $1^{st}$ kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FerrersFunction.html)) with fractional index:
$${_2F_1}\!\left(-\tfrac14,\tfrac54;\,1;\,\tfrac{x}2\right)=P_{\small1/4}(1-x).\tag2$$
Now the integral can be written as
$$S=\int_0^1\left(P_{\small1/4}(1-x)\right)^2dx=\int_0^1\left(P_{\small1/4}(x)\right)^2dx.\tag3$$
To evaluate it, we use formula 7.113 on page 769 in [Gradshteyn & Ryzhyk](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123736374):
$$\int_0^1P_\nu(x)\,P_\sigma(x)\,dx=\\\frac{\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12+\frac\nu2\right)\,\Gamma\left(1+\frac\sigma2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12+\frac\sigma2\right)\,\Gamma\left(1+\frac\nu2\right)}\sin\!\left(\frac{\pi\sigma}2\right)\cos\!\left(\frac{\pi\nu}2\right)-\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12+\frac\sigma2\right)\,\Gamma\left(1+\frac\nu2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12+\frac\nu2\right)\,\Gamma\left(1+\frac\sigma2\right)}\sin\!\left(\frac{\pi\nu}2\right)\cos\!\left(\frac{\pi\sigma}2\right)}{\frac\pi2(\sigma-\nu)(\sigma+\nu+1)}.\tag4$$
Note that in our case $\nu=\sigma=\frac14$, so we cannot use this formula directly because of the term $(\sigma-\nu)$ in the denominator. Instead, we let $\nu=\frac14$ and find the limit for $\sigma\to\frac14$:
$$S=\lim\limits_{\sigma\to{\small1/4}}\int_0^1P_{\small1/4}(x)\,P_\sigma(x)\,dx=\\\lim\limits_{\sigma\to{\small1/4}}\frac{\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac58\right)\,\Gamma\left(1+\frac\sigma2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12+\frac\sigma2\right)\,\Gamma\left(\frac98\right)}\sin\!\left(\frac{\pi\sigma}2\right)\cos\!\left(\frac\pi8\right)-\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12+\frac\sigma2\right)\,\Gamma\left(\frac98\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac58\right)\,\Gamma\left(1+\frac\sigma2\right)}\sin\!\left(\frac\pi8\right)\cos\!\left(\frac{\pi\sigma}2\right)}{\frac\pi2(\sigma-\frac14)(\sigma+\frac54)}.\tag5$$
To evaluate the limit, we use [l'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule). This gives quite a big expression that I will not copy here. It contains values of the gamma and [digamma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html) functions at rational points, that could be simplified to elementary terms using the [Gauss digamma theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssDigammaTheorem.html) and identities given in the [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) and in the famous [Vidūnas paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403510v1.pdf), yielding the desired result $(1)$.

---

Indeed, we can have a more general result:
$$\int_0^1\left({_2F_1}\!\left(-\nu,\nu+1;\,1;\,\tfrac x2\right)\right)^2dx=\int_0^1\left(P_\nu\left(x\right)\right)^2dx=\\\frac{1+\!\left[\psi_0\!\left(1+\frac\nu2\right)-\psi_0\!\left(\frac12+\frac\nu2\right)\right]\frac{\sin(\pi\nu)}\pi}{1+2\nu}.\tag6$$

Comment: +1) Very nice. I had the exact same work up to the evaluation of the final limit via L'Hopital, which for some reason kept coming out wrong so I gave up. Question: did you know all those references off the top of your head or did you have to hunt them down? They look incredibly useful.

Comment: I unsuccessfully tried to solve this problem last year when it was posted. When I saw it again today, I realized that the parameters of the hypergeometric function here match the expression for the Legendre function that read about recently. Then I just looked up that integral in _Gradshteyn & Ryzhik_ and calculated the limit.

Comment: A pleasure to follow your precise and informative elaboration. 1+

Answer (score 17):

Yes, it is possible in some cases, for example,
$$S=\frac{8\sqrt2+4\ln\left(\sqrt2-1\right)}{3\pi}$$

Answer (score 4):

Incomplete solution:

In fact, we have $${}_2F_1(-\frac14,\frac54;1;\frac{x}{2})=\frac{8\sqrt{2}}{\pi\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2x}}}((2+\sqrt{2x})E(\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{x}})-K(\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{x}})).$$

Here $E(m)=\int^1_0\sqrt{\frac{1-mt^2}{1-t^2}}~dt$ and $K(m)=\int^1_0\frac{dt}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-mt^2)}}$ are the complete elliptic integrals

Therefore, by substituting $y=\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{x}}$ (so that $x=\frac{y^2}{(2-y)^2}$), we have $$S=\frac{16}{\pi^2}\int^{2\sqrt{2}-2}_{0}\frac{y}{(2-y)^4}\left(4E(y)-(2-y)K(y)\right)^2~dy.$$

$$%E'(y)=\frac{E(y)-K(y)}{2y}\\K'(y)=\frac{E(y)-(1-y)K(y)}{2y(1-y)}\\\int E(y)dy=\frac{2(1+y)E(y)-2(1-y)K(y)}{3}\\\int K(y)dy=2E(y)-(1-y)K(y)$$

This may be doable with some clever integration by parts.